# Harry Dresden - what impact breaking his word had on his power?

Tags: magical-theory, the-dresden-files

It was mentioned first in *"Grave Peril"*:

> "Poor little poppet. All of your efforts to learn and you still know
>   so little. Harry made a bargain with me long ago - and broke it, once
>   then, and once a few nights past. He swore to uphold it again, last
>   night, and broke it thrice. Now he reaps the consequences of his
>   actions. His own powers turn against him, the poor dear, to encourage
>   him to fulfill his word, to keep his promise."

So question is: when he broke his word, what were the effects on him? In *Grave Peril*, during Bianca's party, he basically became powerless when just meeting Lea there, but there must have been more. Bargains made there and later saw him get it back, but question is: since his first broken bargain with Lea was his power reduced and how?

Was it reducing his output (that is making him weaker)? Or was it siphoning some of his power to Lea? After all the oaths were on his power, so it's not unreasonable to think it was some sort of security on his oath (a lien of sorts)? Was it all the time or just in Nevernever, where Lea had power to exact the payment of the debt?

Or maybe it was just a reminder of his "treachery" - sort of like being pestered by bank: not really bad thing (yet), but annoying to the extreme?

When later Ms Sommerset paid him a visit his debt was a factor, yet it was our world, not Faerie...
And still later, when he renegotiated, did his power - if he had parted with any - retuned to him?

As time passes Harry is getting better with magic, more precise, so it would definitely align with his recognition that he was more economical with it, but was it only that? Was being frugal with power (which is not surprising - he is part Scottish, after all) the only explanation for him getting better and stronger? Or maybe he got back what he lost (if he lost anything)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dresden didn't lose any magic by breaking his word. His magic, instead of bending to his will, started working against him. Whatever mystic forces that dictate the laws of magic deemed him untrustworthy, but his power is still his. Dresden actually stated at least once in one of the books (I don't have a quote in front of me) that that is precisely why wizards need to take their word more seriously than normal humans- they have more power to work against them when they break their word.

The magic system in the Dresden Files is pretty consistent, and Dresden approaches many aspects of his art with near scientific processes and explanations, but it isn't science. The arcane and seemingly fickle rules are sometimes hard to predict even by the mightiest wizard, which is why Dresden didn't plan on getting the use of his power back when he renegotiated with Lea on the bridge. He just needed to get where he was going in a hurry without the Fae stopping him.

His word (and his power) is already restored well before Mab shows up in disguise in the fourth book, so the Queen buying his 'mortgage' doesn't have any influence on his power by that point.

Comment: I will not remove the upvote and mark as answer, but just so you know. I'm currently in the middle of *Cold Days* of my *Dresden Files Marathon*, and  I've already counted three distinct passages (across all books) saying that breaking oath on power diminishes the power of wizard doing it. Severely, at that. Might want to modify the answer. And those passages say so explicitly.

Comment: @AcePL I recommend posting your own answer and accepting it. The topic is something that I would enjoy having a discussion about, but it sounds like you're going to be better versed in the subject. I like my interpretation but that doesn't make it the correct one, and unfortunately I don't have the time to do the research that you've already done.

Comment: It's not really research - I was binge listening to audiobooks, so since I asked about it earlier my attention was drawn to those passages, and curiously they were closer to the end of the series (such as it is at this moment)... And your answer is correct in general, it just needs adding that oathbreaking wizard will see his power reduced. Making a habit of it will rob him of power completely.

Comment: There is a sort of "lease" period you have to fulfill your promise and to backpedal on you breaking it. If you reread "Cold Days", when Harry captures Lacuna, he threatens her with torture, despite giving the word as a Winter Knight that she is his captive and the torture is forbidden. Immediately, power starts leaving him, until he hastily amends it and says he was "just kidding", "thinking out loud" as it were. I just assume that the person he is making oath TO has some level of control how (much) broken the oath is, eg if Lea doesn't consider it broken, then it is not.

Comment: You also got a chance to "make amends" before losing your power completely. And there are also warning signs that the oath is broken, before a part of your power is taken away: Harry's powers go haywire for a while until he makes amends. We also don't know what losing your power means, exactly. Does it mean "unable to use" or "unable to use safely"? We don't know.

Comment: @jo1storm - I don't think your arguments work here. Both instances was the power loss caused by leaving of *The Winter Knight's Mantle* because Harry broke **The Law of Winter**. And yes, "losing power" means exactly that. I think this was explained to Harry by Lea in `The Ghost Story`.

Comment: @AcePL I don't know. It is either much more subtly handled in the books than I noticed or just inconsistent. At one point Harry says "If you break a magical oath, your own power would destroy you." . His powers going haywire so he won't be able to use them safely fits that. As for losing power... I guess it would still count if Harry would slowly lose powers until he only can use Flickum Bickus but not Pyrofuego. He still has it, but can't throw fireballs. The Ghost Story... he is naked soul for most of the book and uses his memories a lot and yet ends up just fine later. Dunno.